# Quero usar ajax para simplesmente atualizar uma tabela que reflete o banco, sem atualizar a página

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho a index.php, que tem lado a lado um formulário de inserção e uma tabela que reflita o banco, nao precisa ter timeout, só quero que quando faço um novo registro na tabela, ele vai aparecer na tabela ao lado, sem fazer refresh na pagina, olha como esta o metodo até agora:

```
 function atualizarTabela(){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "select.php", false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML=xmlhttp.reponseText;                        
            }
```

a div:

```
<div id="tabela"></div>
```

por enquanto estou tentando fazer assim, mas retorna "undefined"

essa pagina select.php até agora só tem um echo dizendo que funcionou, para teste, mas ela vai fazer select no banco e retornar em echo, os resultados da tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No submit do formulário você faz um ajax para salvar e caso positivo adiciona o registro na tabela. O retorno pode ser apenas o valor do registro ou o html da nova linha.
Segue exemplo:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: $form.serialize(),
  })
  .done(function(novoRegistro) {
    $("#tabela table").append(novoRegistro);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("erro ao salvar");
  });
});
```

E em sua div você teria algo como:

```
<div id="tabela">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

E seu `select.php` retornaria o html da nova linha para a tabela por exemplo

```
<tr>
   <td>Registro 1</td>
</tr>
```